# Upcasting and polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions

Could you please help me to understand why do I get a following output?

> **Z**

The code is listed below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
public:
    virtual void shout() { cout << "X"; }
};

class Y : public X {
public:
    void shout() { cout << "Y"; }
};

class Z : public Y {
public:
    void shout() { cout << "Z"; }
};

int main() {

    Y *yz = new Z(); 

    yz -> shout();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `shout` is declared `virtual`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is what you programmed. You declared `shout()` virtual which means that in case of a Z object the Z's `shout()` is executed. This is done also if you do not repeat the `virtual` keyword explicitely. I.e. the `shout()` is considered virtual even if you do not repeat the `virtual` in each derived class (which is optional).

I would repeat the `virtual` keyword anyway and also I would use `override`.

Comment: Does it means that as soon as virtual is mentioned once it becomes virtual in every class?

Comment: Yes. In every derived class.

Answer (score 3):

Since `shout` is declared as `virtual`, C++ will do [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) when it is called, and use `Z`'s version of the method because `Z` is the type of the object.